# UIImagePickerController open in camera roll

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to open camera roll directly with `UIImagePickerController` but still have the back button to your album list?

`UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` will open only the camera roll without the option to slide back to albums.

Comment: I tried looping through all subviews and sub-sub views where it picked  up one `UITableView`. My intention was to explicitly call `[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];` but I immediately receive an `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error when calling it. It's as if the view has been released from memory or something.

Comment: @eyal Dug into this a bit more today. There isn't a practical way to do this. Unfortunately, it seems my answer below of "it can't be done" is the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is -- it's not possible. At least not through any standard interface. It might be possible to do some view hierarchy mining or method swizzling to make it happen, but then you may run afoul of the App Store submissions review.

From the [Camera Programming Topics of iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html) (bolded emphasis mine):

> Instead of using the camera as the media source, you use the Camera
>   Roll album **or** Saved Photos album, **or** the entire photo library.

And:

> **Source type** To configure the picker for browsing saved media as
>   opposed to capturing a new picture or movie, set its sourceType
>   property to one of the saved photo sources:
>
> Use `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` to present a browser that
>   provides access to **all the photo albums on the device**, including the Camera
>   Roll album on devices that have a camera.
>
> Use `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` to present a browser that
>   **restricts access to the Camera Roll album** on devices that have a camera, or to the 
>   Saved Photos album on devices that don’t.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest you to use custom imagepickers like elcimagepicker.
afer going through the code properly you can achieve the thing you want with the help of minor manipulations.

Comment: I am unhappy that the trolls who want to get badges for negative reviews took on this answer. There is a valid point here, and an also a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same situation.And found a solution,here's the code.Hope it helps.

```
pImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
id albumCtrller = pImagePicker.topViewController;
pImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[pImagePicker pushViewController: albumCtrller animated: NO];
```

Now you can open album and have a back navigatebutton.

Comment: Did your app pass Apple review process or get rejected?